# Ubuntu not saving files and settings when running from flash drive

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, persistence

How can I make Ubuntu run completely off of a flash drive?

I have downloaded Ubuntu onto a 4gb flash drive but no changes I make are saved between sessions.  I want to be able to run and save everything I do to the flash drive. I don't want it interfering with my hard drive at all.  I just want to be able to plug my flash drive in the computer boot Ubuntu, and for it to save my changes.

E.g. When I install Google Chrome, when I reboot it isn't there.

Comment: Just to make it clear, you aren't running Live-USB session but installation from USB?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to install Ubuntu on the flash drive with dedicated storage. If you use *UNetbootin* to create your flash drive you can specify how much space you want to allocate to the persistent storage. In the image below I allocated 2GB to it as an example.

[image]

If you want to use the flash drive to run Ubuntu I would recommend allocating all the free space to on the disk to it. The obvious advantage being you will have more room to install your favorite applications.

Comment: I feel dumb. when i installed it i didnt allow any memory for saves.... duhh so sorry

Comment: no worries. Please accept my answer then so this will not keep showing up in Unanswered questions. Btw, welcome to askubuntu! :)